# Node Request Causes PC to Run PROXY on Startup

Tags: node.js

Hello so I am a noob at coding and I ran this curl request in my cmd with out really uh knowing the consequences. I cannot figure out how to just run local host every time my pc starts up and remove this. Also why doesn't this code work when I paste it into a script and run it with node? The real code doesn't have asrics and has the real info.
The code only works when I paste it into node console.

```js
var http = require("http");
var options = {
  host: "**.*****.***",
  port: 5959,
  path: "yeezysupply.com",
  headers: {
    Host: "yeezysupply.com",
    'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('username-cc-US' + ':' + 'Password').toString('base64'),
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36", // Chrome
  }
};
http.get(options, function(response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
  });
}).on("error", function(e) {
  console.log('error :(', e);
});
```